# Client Cache not being invalidated after app deployment with Business Application Studio

Tags: sap-fiori, sap-web-ide, sap-business-application-studio

We've recently changed from SAP Web IDE to SAP Business Application Studio (BAS). With Web IDE, the latest version of changes to a custom app was loaded in the browser automatically after deployment to our on-premise system. If I deploy a custom app with BAS, I have to manually run `ui2/invalidate_client_caches` to see the latest version in the browser of the app I've just deployed.

Any idea what the reason could be?